# Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment in uft

Tags: vb.net, qtp, hp-uft

Thanks in Advance :) I can get the row count but not the column count using columncount method in uft 12.2. It simples throws an error at `AccNoCol=AccNoTB.ColumnCount`Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment: 'AccNoTB.ColumnCount'. I know the column count is 8 here however they are dynamic & there is a risk to hard code the column count in script. Could you plz point out the correct? Thanks again

```
Set AccNoTB=browser("title:=.*").page("title:=.*").webtable("column names:=;Account No;Account Name;Billing City;Website;Phone;Assigned To;Action","cols:=8")

AccNoRow=AccNoTB.RowCount

AccNoCol=AccNoTB.ColumnCount

AccTBvalue=AccNoTB.GetCellData(AccNoRow,AccNoCol)

MsgBox AccTBvalue`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The column count of each row in the `WebTable` can differ therefore `ColumnCount` requires a parameter to specify to UFT which row's column count you're interested in.

```html
A row can have
<table border=1>
  <tr><td>One</td></tr>
  <tr><td>or</td><td>two</td></tr>
  <tr><td>or</td><td>even</td><td>more</td></tr>
</table>
Columns
```

Answer (score 0):

Two simple ways to get ***Row*** and ***Column*** counts.

Note that I've removed `"cols:=8"` from object description, assuming the WebTablt is getting identified by `column names`.

```
Set AccNoTB=browser("title:=.*").page("title:=.*").webtable("column names:=;Account No;Account Name;Billing City;Website;Phone;Assigned To;Action")
```

Two ways to get Rows count

```
AccNoRow = AccNoTB.GetROProperty("rows")    '<-- 1
AccNoRow = AccNoTB.RowCount                 '<-- 2
```

Two ways to get Column count

```
AccNoCol = AccNoTB.GetROProperty("cols")    '<-- 1
iRow = 2
AccNoCol = AccNoTB.ColumnCount(iRow)        '<-- 2 This way is useful when you have different columns in different rows.
```

Now lets take the example that @Motti have given. In this case we'll run a loop and get the column count.

```
Set AccNoTB=browser("title:=.*").page("title:=.*").webtable("column names:=;Account No;Account Name;Billing City;Website;Phone;Assigned To;Action")
AccNoRow = AccNoTB.RowCount

For i = 1 To AccNoRow
    AccNoCol = AccNoTB.ColumnCount(i)
    Print "Row " & i & " has " && " column/s."
Next
```

Output:

```
Row 1 has 1 column/s.
Row 2 has 2 column/s.
Row 3 has 3 column/s.
```

Answer (score -1):

```
set a=Browser("OrangeHRM").Page("OrangeHRM_2").WebTable("micclass:=WebTable","html tag:=TABLE")

co=a.RowCount

MsgBox co
'set b=Browser("OrangeHRM").Page("OrangeHRM_2").WebTable("micclass:=WebTable","html tag:=TABLE")

col=b.ColumnCount

MsgBox col
```

Comment: Explain what you're doing and why it's an answer to the question